# How to show recycler view when i click an item in another recyclerview

Tags: java, android, xml-parsing

I have used two `Recyclerview` inside a `Recyclerview` item. My problem is I want to hide the `recyclerview(kitchen grocery)` of 1st item(fruits and vegetable) when the user clicks 2nd item `(fruits and vegetable)` and have to show that particular items recycled view. Herewith I have attached the images of my requirement for your understanding.Please tell me a solution .when I click the second item the first items recyclerview should hide.How to achieve this.[image: when I click the second item the first items recyclerview should hide.How to achieve this.] Thanks in Advance.

Comment: why don't use `ExpandableListView` ?

Comment: Is this  ExpendableListView kind of arrangement ?

Comment: yeah...u r correct

Answer (score 0):

yes...Using Expandablelistview has solved my problem.here is the link for expandablelistview https://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/

This tutorial will show expand of all item.So replace this code in main activity to expand one item.

```
        expListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new OnGroupExpandListener() {

        // TODO Colapse Here Using this... in android
        int previousGroup = -1;
        boolean flag = false;

        @Override
        public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {

        //  Log.e("keshav", "onGroupClick is -> " + groupPosition);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    listDataHeader.get(groupPosition) + " Expanded",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            if (groupPosition != previousGroup && flag) {
                expListView.collapseGroup(previousGroup);
            }
            previousGroup = groupPosition;

            flag = true;

        }
    });
```